# Google App Engine - Installing SugarCRM possible?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mamp, sugarcrm

Is this possible?
I'm trying to just test the package out, and Google App Engine is what i currently have available.

Or is there another way to just set it up locally? I was hoping to be able to test it on the internet with Google but maybe that is not possible..
I managed to get it to start the installation process, but then i ran into then first setup instruction which was to have zip support and i do not know how to activate that for php on Mac.

**EDIT:**

Nevermind i did it with MAMP, here's the guide i used in case anyone needs it for future use:
http://dogstar.org/drupal/content/sugarcrm-creating-local-install

Here's a shameless copy of matthews instructions in case they ever get inaccessible, they helped me at least..

> I am on a quest for good customer relationship management software. My
>   preference is to find an opensource solution. There are Drupal and
>   Joomla based solutions like Civi-CRM. At some point I'll sit down and
>   set up Civi-CRM and see what I think about it. However, a few days ago
>   I downloaded SugarCRM CE (Community Edition) and created a local
>   install of it. I've started the process of evaluating it.
>
> If you are interested in setting up a local install, in many ways it
>   is similar to setting up a Drupal install. First you need to have MAMP
>   (for a Mac), WAMP (for a Windows box), or LAMP (for Linux) set up on
>   your computer. Do a Google search and you'll find plenty of
>   information on any one of these. Basically, it stands for
>   Mac-Windows-Linux, Apache, MySQL,and PHP.
>
> Next, download SugarCRM HERE.
>
> Next...
>
> 1. Extract the instance of SugarCRM you want to install
> 2. Pop extracted directory into MAMP's htdocs folder--
>      /applications/MAMP/htdocs
> 3. Fire up MAMP and click on "Open Start Page"
> 4. Click on phpMyAdmin in the menu bar at the top of the page
> 5. Click on the "databases" link in the main body of the page
> 6. At the bottom of this page is a text box that reads "create new
>      database", type in a name for your new database and choose a
>      "collation", I use latin1_swedish_ci
> 7. Create a user for the database--click on the sql tab up top and use
>      the following command "grant all on database_name_accounts.* to
>      user_name@localhost identified by 'password';" with no quotes and
>      replacing database_name_accounts with the database, user_name with
>      any name you care to put in, and password with an password you care
>      to use
> 8. In your browser go to `http://localhost:8888` and click on the
>      directory with SugarCRM in it. You should get a splash screen. Read
>      the screen and scroll down to next at the bottom. Click. Click on
>      next and Read the License--click on the Accept box and click "next".
> 9. It will check your system for all needed components and then bring
>      you to a page which asks which type of installation you want to
>      engage in. Choose "Typical". Click "next". It will indicate it has
>      detected MySQL. Click "next".
> 10. Enter your DB name, your hostname, the username and password for
>        the user you created in the MySQL database in step 7.
> 11. It will "Verify DB Credentials". Click "I Accept".
> 12. Enter an Admin Password in the next screen. Click "next".
> 13. Enter your "locale settings". Click "next".
> 14. Print your settings, if desired, and click "install".
> 15. Wait while the script finishes setting up the software and click
>        "next".
> 16. Fill out the registration. Click "send registration".
> 17. This will bring you to your login page. Enter the username "Admin"
>        and whatever password you created in step 15.
> 18. Choose your timezone.
>
> There you have it. SugarCRM CE is now set up locally on your computer.
>   Please remember that you must have MAMP, WAMP, or LAMP (depending on
>   your computer's OS) running for SugarCRM to run.

Comment: +1 I am still interested in the question in its original form.

Comment: Agreed, I'd like to see an answer here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind i did it with MAMP, here's the guide i used in case anyone needs it for future use:
http://dogstar.org/drupal/content/sugarcrm-creating-local-install

Here's a shameless copy of matthews instructions in case they ever get inaccessible, they helped me at least..

> I am on a quest for good customer relationship management software. My
>   preference is to find an opensource solution. There are Drupal and
>   Joomla based solutions like Civi-CRM. At some point I'll sit down and
>   set up Civi-CRM and see what I think about it. However, a few days ago
>   I downloaded SugarCRM CE (Community Edition) and created a local
>   install of it. I've started the process of evaluating it.
>
> If you are interested in setting up a local install, in many ways it
>   is similar to setting up a Drupal install. First you need to have MAMP
>   (for a Mac), WAMP (for a Windows box), or LAMP (for Linux) set up on
>   your computer. Do a Google search and you'll find plenty of
>   information on any one of these. Basically, it stands for
>   Mac-Windows-Linux, Apache, MySQL,and PHP.
>
> Next, download SugarCRM HERE.
>
> Next...
>
> 1. Extract the instance of SugarCRM you want to install
> 2. Pop extracted directory into MAMP's htdocs folder--
>      /applications/MAMP/htdocs
> 3. Fire up MAMP and click on "Open Start Page"
> 4. Click on phpMyAdmin in the menu bar at the top of the page
> 5. Click on the "databases" link in the main body of the page
> 6. At the bottom of this page is a text box that reads "create new
>      database", type in a name for your new database and choose a
>      "collation", I use latin1_swedish_ci
> 7. Create a user for the database--click on the sql tab up top and use
>      the following command "grant all on database_name_accounts.* to
>      user_name@localhost identified by 'password';" with no quotes and
>      replacing database_name_accounts with the database, user_name with
>      any name you care to put in, and password with an password you care
>      to use
> 8. In your browser go to `http://localhost:8888` and click on the
>      directory with SugarCRM in it. You should get a splash screen. Read
>      the screen and scroll down to next at the bottom. Click. Click on
>      next and Read the License--click on the Accept box and click "next".
> 9. It will check your system for all needed components and then bring
>      you to a page which asks which type of installation you want to
>      engage in. Choose "Typical". Click "next". It will indicate it has
>      detected MySQL. Click "next".
> 10. Enter your DB name, your hostname, the username and password for
>        the user you created in the MySQL database in step 7.
> 11. It will "Verify DB Credentials". Click "I Accept".
> 12. Enter an Admin Password in the next screen. Click "next".
> 13. Enter your "locale settings". Click "next".
> 14. Print your settings, if desired, and click "install".
> 15. Wait while the script finishes setting up the software and click
>        "next".
> 16. Fill out the registration. Click "send registration".
> 17. This will bring you to your login page. Enter the username "Admin"
>        and whatever password you created in step 15.
> 18. Choose your timezone.
>
> There you have it. SugarCRM CE is now set up locally on your computer.
>   Please remember that you must have MAMP, WAMP, or LAMP (depending on
>   your computer's OS) running for SugarCRM to run.